# Why does `include <iostream>` end up including so *many* files?

Tags: c++, include, iostream

Follow up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847822/name-collision-in-c):

When I do `include <iostream>`.
It happens that it includes many files from `/usr/include` .A `grep "\usr\include"` over `g++ -E prog.cpp` counted to about 1260 entries ;).

Is their a way to control including various files?
Platform: Linux
G++ version: 4.2.4

Comment: g++ -E output contains line number information. That grep shows up loads of repetition of file names, that has nothing to do with the number of files included. Try `g++ -E prog.cpp | grep -o "/usr/include[^ ]*" | sort -u | wc -l`. I get 44 hits for /usr/include, and 78 for /usr/lib.

Comment: yeah i was unable to figure out that regex

Comment: <iostream> is a somewhat heavy header.  Can you instead include one of the targeted headers like <ostream> or <istream>?  Furthermore, if you're looking to reduce interheader dependencies, you may be able to use <iosfwd> to pull in forward declarations if you're not accessing any of the members in your header (e.g. if you're just using stream references, pointers, etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `<iostream>` includes them because it depends on them directly, or it's dependancies depend on them.

Ain't nothing you can do about it.

You can (depending on your compiler) limit the effect this has on compilation times by using [Precompiled Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is not to worry about how many files the compiler is including.  Focus more on **correctness, robustness,**  and **schedule**.  If build time is a concern, get a faster machine, build overnight, go on a walk, or divide the code into smaller *translation units*.  Translation units should be small enough to contain code that doesn't change often. **Changes are EVIL.**

The foundation of the build system is to compile only the few files that have changed.  If your development process is functioning correctly, the build time will reside more and more in the linking phase as the project grows.

If the compile time is still lengthy, see if your compiler supports *precompiled headers*.  Generally, this is method for the compiler to store all the declarations and definitions in a more efficient form.

Answer (score 2):

You `#include <iostream>` when you need to use streams.  That should define some things you need.  How much activity it needs to do this is a quality of implementation issue.  You could remove files from `/usr/include`, but that would break things.

I really doubt it's including 1260 files.  Almost certainly most of those are duplicate entries that don't load anything but aren't pruned from the `-E` output.